# Avoiding well-definition of a morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let's take in account for example the groups case (but we should take any other algebraic structure which admits quotient). Let's take $H,H'$ (additive) groups. Let's suppose the first one is a quotient $H=G/K$, for some $G$ group and $K\lhd G$ be some normal subgroup of $G$.

Our problem is, given $\phi:H\to H'$, to show that it is a group isomorphism.

My first thought is to show that $\phi$ is well defined, that is, it does NOT depend on the representative (i.e. if $g_1,g_2$ are two distinct element of $G$ such that $h_1=h_2$ where $h_1:=g_1+K$ and $h_2:=g_2+K$ then $\phi(h_1)=\phi(h_2)$).

This situation is not always simple to treat.

So we can take another path: searching some $\xi:H'\to H$ and showing that it is a group isomorphism which inverts $\phi$. Dealing with $\xi$ we wouldn't have no more problem with good definition and maybe this latter question could be simpler to solve (even I suspect that the problem of good definition of $\phi$ will turn -in some way- into injectivity of $\xi$).

My question is the following: am I right? Can I avoid the problem of good definition of $\phi$ by working with $\xi$? Can I prove that $\phi$ is an isomorphism "simply" by searching a function, proving it is an isomorphism which inverts $\phi$?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't follow the setup of your problem.  You introduce two (abelian?) groups $H,H'$.  The first of these groups happens to be the quotient of some other group $G$, $H = G/K$.  Then without further information, how would one expect to show a mapping $\phi: H \to H'$ is a group homomorphism, much less an *isomorphism*?  Something is missing.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't exahustive enough. Sorry. Suppose to know how does the morphism $\phi$ work: you know $h\mapsto\phi(h)$. You have such an object and you have to prove that is an isomorphism. But we have some problems with well definition. Did I better explained?

Comment: The term "well-defined" usually means that in the way one tries to define something, a reference is made to a choice that can be made in more than one way.  Unless the multiplicity introduced by that choice can be shown to cancel out in a later step in the construction, there is a flaw in the "definition", because the final outcome could be more than one thing (not "well-defined").   In your case you "[s]uppose to know how does the morphism $\phi$ work", so it is unclear where the problem of definition enters in.  If $\phi$ has a known definition, check the group isomorphishm definition.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you could try to solve a problem this way. The issue here is that it is often very difficult to construct a map $\xi:H'\to H$, whereas the map $\phi:H=G/K\to H'$ might be obvious. Additionally, this approach is not going to be helpful if $H'$ is also a quotient group. (For example, the 3rd isomorphism theorem is proved by constructing an isomorphism $H/H\cap N\to HN/N$. Giving a map $HN/N\to H/H\cap N$ is not so easy and, anyway, you still need to check that the map is well-defined.)

A better way to avoid checking if a map $G/K\to H'$ is well defined is to take advantage of some machinery.

**Theorem:** *(First Isomorphism Theorem)* Suppose
$$\phi:G\to H'$$
is a surjective homomorphism and $K=\ker\phi$. Then, there is an isomorphism $\overline{\phi}:G/K\to H'$.

One of the wonderful features of this theorem is that it checks that the map $\overline{\phi}$ is well-defined for you. In fact, this is how the 3rd isomorphism theorem is proved:

The map $H\to HN/N$ given by $h\mapsto hN$ is clearly a homomorphism, and there is no need to check that it is well-defined. The map is surjective since $hnN=hN$ for every $h\in H$ and $n\in N$, and the kernel of this map is obviously $H\cap N$. Invoking the first isomorphism theorem yields the result.